# I want to use a ColumnTransformer to preprocess my dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a DataFrame `df`

- I want to drop any columns in `df` containing 40% null values
- I want to use `SimpleImputer` with strategy `most_frequent` to deal
  with the remaining null values in columns
- I want to convert the non-numerical columns of `df` into numbers (perhaps using `OrdinalEncoder`)
- Finally, I want to one-hot encode certain columns of `df`

I believe that I can use `ColumnTransformer` to encapsulate all of this stuff into one thing. But I am open to learn about what you feel is the Best Strategy for this problem. Please can you show me how?

Background information: Doing my first project in Data science; amateur!

**Edit 1**
Here is a 'sample' of my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'respondent_id': [0,1],
    'h1n1_concern': [1,3],
    'h1n1_knowledge': [0,2],
    'behavioral_antiviral_meds': [0, 0],
    'behavioral_avoidance': [0, 1],
    'behavioral_face_mask': [0, 0],
    'behavioral_wash_hands': [0, 1],
    'behavioral_large_gatherings': [0, 0],
    'behavioral_outside_home': [1, 1],
    'behavioral_touch_face': [1, 1],
    'doctor_recc_h1n1': [0,0],
    'doctor_recc_seasonal': [0,0],
    'chronic_med_condition': [0,0],
    'child_under_6_months': [0,0],
    'health_worker': [0,0],
    'health_insurance': [1,1],
    'opinion_h1n1_vacc_effective': [3,5],
    'opinion_h1n1_risk': [1,4],
    'opinion_h1n1_sick_from_vacc': [2,4],
    'opinion_seas_vacc_effective': [2,4],
    'opinion_seas_risk': [1,2],
    'opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc': [2,4],
    'age_group': ['55-64 Years', '35-44 Years'],
    'education': ['< 12 Years', '12 Years'],
    'race': ['White', 'White'],
    'sex': ['Female', 'Male'],
    'income_poverty': ['Below Poverty', 'Below Poverty'],
    'marital_status': ['Not Married', 'Not Married'],
    'rent_or_own': ['Own', 'Rent'],
    'employment_status': ['Not in Labor Force', 'Employed'],
    'hhs_geo_region': ['oxchjgsf', 'bhuqouqj'],
    'census_msa': ['Non-MSA', 'MSA, Not Principle City'],
    'household_adults': [0, 0],
    'household_children': [0, 0],
    'employment_industry': [np.nan, 'pxcmvdjn'],
    'employment_occupation': [np.nan, 'xgwztkwe']
}
)
```

[image: Here are the first two rows in CSV/Excel]

**Edit 2**
Here are the list of columns which contain non-numerical values (I want to OrdinalEncode them):

```
columns_to_be_converted_into_numbers = [
    'age_group','education','income_poverty',
    'race', 'employment_status',
    'hhs_geo_region', 'census_msa', 'employment_industry', 'employment_occupation',
    'sex', 'marital_status', 'rent_or_own'
]
```

Here are the columns which I want to one-hot encode (because they contain nominal data):

```
columns_to_be_one_hot_encoded = [
    'race', 'employment_status', 
    'hhs_geo_region', 'census_msa', 'employment_industry', 'employment_occupation'
]
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of the dataframe you are working with?

Comment: Sir, I have the DataFrame as a CSV file. How do I share a sample here on GitHub?

Comment: You can copy a few of the first rows from the csv and paste them here into a code block. It should maintain formattting.

Comment: Yes sir, I have these are the first two rows of my DataFrame. You can copy paste it without any tension, I have made sure that it works.

Answer (score 1):

To drop the null you can do something like

```
df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() < .4]
```

Since you want to apply multi-step preprocessing for at least some columns (e.g., imputation and then one-hot encoding), you may need a sequential pipeline for each set of columns.
Note a column transformer performs transformation for different columns **in parallel, not sequentially**. So you will need to feed the sequential pipelines into the column transformer in the last stage of preprocessing.

See the accepted answer from the link below for examples.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/81479/sklearn-how-to-create-a-sequential-pipeline